# Understanding below MySQL logic

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a piece of MySQL code which is running in the background of one of the website.

I am trying to understand what the `new` column means.
Would any customer with a single order be flagged as new = 1?

Code is seen below:

```
select
a.id_order,
IF((
        SELECT so.id_order 
        FROM `orders` so 
        WHERE so.id_customer = a.id_customer 
        AND 
        so.id_order < a.id_order 
        LIMIT 1) > 0, 0, 1) as new               // new keyword

        FROM `orders` a 

        LEFT JOIN `customer` c ON 
       (c.`id_customer` = a.`id_customer`)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me assume that `id_order` is never negative or zero.

Then the query is returning "0" if an order for the customer has a smaller id.  The intention would be to flag the first order.

If a customer has only one order, then its value would always be 1, because the subquery would return `NULL`.

I would write the logic:

```
SELECT o.id_order,
       (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM orders so
                    WHERE so.id_customer = o.id_customer AND
                          so.id_order < o.id_order
                   )
       ) as is_first_order
FROM orders o LEFT JOIN
     customer c
     ON c.id_customer = o.id_customer;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` should be unnecessary if all orders have customers.  In fact, the `JOIN` is not necessary at all, you can just use:

```
select o.id_order,
       (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM orders so
                    WHERE so.id_customer = o.id_customer AND
                          so.id_order < o.id_order
                   )
       ) as is_first_order
FROM orders o ;
```

Answer (score 0):

"new" here is the name of the column result of the if statement between brackets

```
((
        SELECT so.id_order 
        FROM `orders` so 
        WHERE so.id_customer = a.id_customer 
        AND 
        so.id_order < a.id_order 
        LIMIT 1) > 0, 0, 1)
```

IF

```
(SELECT so.id_order 
FROM `orders` so 
WHERE so.id_customer = a.id_customer 
AND so.id_order < a.id_order 
LIMIT 1)
```

Greater than 0 then the "new" column value will be 0
Else it will be 1